# Analysis of algorithm complexity on linked lists

Tags: algorithm, linked-list

Please suggest me some good materials or books or links that provede the methods to find the complexity of algorithms  that use linked list for their implementation. My question may sound silly to some of you but please reply.Please help

Comment: I know.But please help if you can.

Comment: ??? the same way you find the complexity for any other algorithms. You would be better asking about the *place where you are getting stuck* trying to do it for yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[*Introduction to Algorithms*](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Introduction-Algorithms-T-Cormen/dp/0262533057/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1313324843&sr=8-1) is the canonical textbook.

It is possible to find a complete PDF of this book online.  I'm not going to provide a link, though, because I'm not sure if these copies are legal.

If all you're after is a quick reference, then Wikipedia is the best place to start.  For instance, see the table at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list#Tradeoffs.

Comment: i  have this book and it's a classic one but not for beginners.If you can please suggest some books or links of my interest

Comment: @gautam: It **is** for beginners!  It's the companion textbook for an introductory first-year MIT course!

Comment: Thanks.Actually I want to learn those linked list related parts only.If you can please tell me those parts that deals with complexity of linked list related algorithms because I am not able to find it.Please help.

Comment: @gautam did you just want to know the big-O notation of common linked-list operations?

Comment: @gautam: Is the table at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list#Tradeoffs what you're after?

Comment: @gautam refer to Oli's link, it's the answer to your question.

Answer (score 1):

Gautam I have a feeling that you are trying to skip the understanding of 'complexity analysis' portion and jump to  linked-list-complexity-analysis.
Just so you know, if you want to understand it truly, then you have to understand two parts
 1. How to compute complexity of an algorithm
 2. The flow of algorithm in question.

'linked-list-complexity-analysis '  is not something that you can understand without understanding {1}
That said, if at all you want ready answer (trust me that wouldnt help you in interviews), you can refer to this book "Data structures and algorithm and applications in C++"  (http://www.mhhe.com/engcs/compsci/sahni/)
Highly recommended for beginner. 
Immensely boring, and I doubt you will read it again. :P
You will find answers to your specific questions there.

After you are done with that book , I would suggest go with DataStructures using C/C++ by Langsam/tennenbaum.